# Should [Foreign-beer] exist as a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

All 11 questions for [foreign-beer](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign-beer) are asking about how to get beer from one place another place and given the international nature of stack exchange these range from buying American micro-brews in Europe to getting beers from one country in Europe in another country to asking where to find microbrewed beers in the country they are made in.

Comment: All across this site are a number of tags being used for the sake of finding a tag to put on a tag on a question we need to start getting the wikis sorted for tags so people really know how to use them

Comment: I agree, but every beer is foreign beer to someone unless we pick a primary locality first it to reference

Comment: Very true I agree with your points lets give it some time for the community to have there say and we will take some action

Answer (score 4):

The concept of "foreign" on a worldwide site isn't meaningful.  If these questions are about transporting alcohol across national boundaries, we should come up with a tag that's about that *transportation*.  If the questions are about the beers themselves, we should use tags that are about the type of beer (or wine or spirit, for those cases).

A quick glance at the 11 questions currently using this tag shows no solid unifying theme to me.

**Edit:** I've retagged the questions that had this tag.  In doing so, I made the following distinction:

- *Location* tags (e.g. [italy](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italy)) are about *places*, like where to buy such-and-such in that place.  Location tags are names of countries, regions, states, etc.
- *Local-style* tags (e.g. [german-beers](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german-beers)) are about *products* that happen to have a geographical connection.  The locale is an adjective and the tag also contains a noun, like "beers".  Remember that our scope could include German wines alongside German beers, so "German" by itself isn't precise enough.

We probably have some tags that should be renamed (I already renamed "german" to "german-beers").  If you find them, please let us know -- mods can rename tags without individually editing the questions they're on.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't see a unifying them or imagine a use case for it as its currently being tagged.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that all 11  foreign beer tags deal with the question of getting beer from one location to another and seeing that we have expanded our site to include wines and other alcohols, should we change the this tag to an **international sales** tag when it comes to trying to obtain something that is not normally sold in the country of a particular OP? This tag would suffice for all alcohol sales on this site. I do not know if this is a good suggestion for everyone here or not. I am simply putting in my two pits into the question..